# Pass connection from Java Application to Birt report

Tags: java, connection, datasource, birt

I'm new to Birt.

I'm trying to pass the connection to the report from my java application, but I get an error:

> The following items have errors:
>
> ReportDesign (id = 1):
>   + There are errors evaluating script "importPackage(Packages.it.lfiammetta.birt); var conn = new
>   ReportRenderer(); 
>   reportContext.getAppContext().put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection",
>   conn);": Fail to execute script in function __bm_beforeOpen(). Source:
>
> " + importPackage(Packages.it.lfiammetta.birt); var conn = new
>   ReportRenderer(); 
>   reportContext.getAppContext().put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection",
>   conn); + "
>
> A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
>   Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error:
>   ReferenceError: "ReportRenderer" is not defined.
>   (/report/data-sources/oda-data-source[@id="43"]/method[@name="beforeOpen"]#2)
>   Script source:
>   /report/data-sources/oda-data-source[@id="43"]/method[@name="beforeOpen"],
>   line: 0, text:
>   __bm_beforeOpen(). (Element ID:1)

This is my java code that creates and launches report:

```
package it.lfiammetta.birt;

public class ReportRenderer {
        public void executeReport() {
                code...

                Map<String, Object> appContext = task.getAppContext();
                appContext.put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection", myConnection);
                appContext.put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnectionCloseAfterUse", false);
                task.setAppContext(appContext);

                task.run();

                code...
        }
}
```

This is the code I wrote in the script 'beforeOpen' the datasource:

```
importPackage(Packages.it.lfiammetta.birt);

var conn = new ReportRenderer(); 
reportContext.getAppContext().put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection", conn);
```

I set the classpath.

Birt version I'm using is 4.2.1.

Thanks in advance for your help and I apologize for my English.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing that from Java code (`IJDBCParameters` - actually parameters for JDBC connections, I'm looking connection by name - `OdaDataSourceHandle.getName()`):

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static void substituteJDBCConnections(IReportRunnable pReportRunnable) {
    final Map<String, IJDBCParameters> jdbcConnections = reportParameters.getJdbcConnections();
    if (jdbcConnections != null ){
        for (Iterator iter = pReportRunnable.getDesignHandle().getModuleHandle().getDataSources().iterator(); iter.hasNext();){
            // http://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_-_Execute_Modified_Report_(BIRT)
            Object element = iter.next();
            if (element instanceof OdaDataSourceHandle){
                OdaDataSourceHandle dsHandle = (OdaDataSourceHandle) element;
                String key = dsHandle.getName();
                if (key == null){
                    continue;
                }
                IJDBCParameters jdbcParams = jdbcConnections.get(key);
                if (jdbcParams == null){
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    dsHandle.setProperty( "odaDriverClass", jdbcParams.getDriverName());
                    dsHandle.setProperty( "odaURL", jdbcParams.getConnectionString());
                    dsHandle.setProperty( "odaUser", jdbcParams.getUserName());
                    dsHandle.setProperty( "odaPassword", jdbcParams.getPassword());
                } catch (SemanticException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you fixed your issue already, but maybe someone will be looking for this in the future. First of all 4.2.x versions had problems with passed connections. I did not observed the same errors in 4.4.2.

Other thing, I do not get why you are trying to pass `ReportRenderer` as a connection in lines:

```
var conn = new ReportRenderer();
reportContext.getAppContext().put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection", conn);
```

The passed object in here should be a `java.sql.Connection` object.

Therefore,

```
Map<String, Object> appContext = task.getAppContext();
appContext.put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection", myConnection);
appContext.put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnectionCloseAfterUse", false);
task.setAppContext(appContext);
```

looks correct as long as `myConnection` is an implementation of `java.sql.Connection`